# Displaying a Google Chart Using Django

Tags: django, django-templates, google-visualization

I have generated a variable `data` in Django with the following format:

```
data = [['100',10],['90',9],['80',8]]
```

and I've passed it off to my template using render_to_response:

```
return render_to_response('template.html', {
                                            'data': data,
                                            },
                                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the template header I have placed a call to Google Charts to generate a line chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Number');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Number/10');
  data.addRows( {{ data }} );

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, title: "Numbers"});
}
</script>
```

When I do this, nothing is displayed.  If I strip the strings out of `data` and try again, the chart appears, but obviously with no x-axis labels.

I have also tried adding the data using the arrayToDataTable function:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Number', 'Number/10'],
      {% for datum in data %}
          {{ datum }},
      {% endfor %}],
      false);
```

but this again fails to display any chart.

Any suggestions on how I can change one of the above, or try another approach to get the x-axis labels to appear?

Comment: I've confirmed that the arrayToDataTable approach will display if the strings are removed as well.  I can also display multiple curves with either approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to disable the autoescaping of your results. You can do so by adding the safe filter:

```
data.addRows( {{ data|safe }} );
```

or

```
{% autoescape off %}
[...]
    {{ data }}
[...]
{% endautoescape %}
```

My advice is, if you can install additional packages, to use one of these wrappers:

- http://code.google.com/p/google-chartwrapper/ (last updated 2011)
- https://github.com/jacobian/django-googlecharts/ (archived 2017)
- https://code.google.com/p/django-graphs/ (last updated 2008)

Comment: The safe data tip looked great but I've tried it in various combinations (just |safe, |safe with autoescape, both data loading approaches, etc.) with no luck.  googlecharts looks interesting; I'll give it a try.  Tx for the suggestions.

Comment: Scratch that, |safe works with the first data approach as you indicate.  I had another error that obscured the result.  Tx!